# what is meaning of () in perl?

Tags: perl

I have this code

```
my $line = "Data=&quot;3&";

my ($count) = ($line =~ /Data=&quot;([^&]+)/x);

print "$count\n"; # prints 3

my $count = ($line =~ /Data=&quot;([^&]+)/x);

print "$count\n"; #print 1
```

What influence do the parentheses have on the result?

Comment: The parens force the use of the list assignment operator, which causes the regex match be evaluated in list context. See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129). The regex match results different results depending on whether it's evaluated in scalar or list context.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, parentheses have the same function in Perl as they do in most other programming languages: to disambiguate the order of evaluation

In the case of

```
my $count = ($line =~ /Data=&quot;([^&]+)/x)
```

they force the regex match to happen before the assignment. In this case they make no difference because they are enforcing the default priority

With

```
my ($count) = ($line =~ /Data=&quot;([^&]+)/x)
```

the right-hand pair of parentheses is doing the same as before, and is unnecessary. But `($count)` turns the left-hand-side of the assignment from a simple scalar into a *list of scalars*

This is critical because it imposes *list context*, and every operator and subroutine call has a different behaviour in list context from *scalar context*

If you read
[*Regexp Quote-Like Operators*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)
in `perldoc perlop` you will see that the match `m//` operator that you are using

- Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails

In list context it's more complex because the behaviour depends on whether the regex has the `/g` (global) modifier and whether it uses any captures. In this case, with a single capture and without `/g`, this is the relevant clause

- Returns a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern

What all this means is that in *scalar context*—the first example—`$count` will be set to *true* or *false* according to whether the regex pattern matched. In *list context*—the second example—it will be set to the contents of the capture `([^&]+)`. If the match failed then the regex match will return an empty list, so `$count` will be set to `undef`

Answer (score 2):

The parens in this case force the left hand side (LHS) into list context. Some subroutines can make decisions based on whether the caller wants a list or a scalar, other ones will return Perl defaults (often unexpected results) if called in differing contexts:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $list_count = context();  # scalar context requested
my @list = context();        # list context requested
my ($x, $y, $z) = context(); # list context requested

my @arr = want_array();         # sub decides what to return (list)
my ($x, $y, $z) = want_array(); # same (list)
my $first_elem = want_array();  # same (scalar)

sub context {
    # this sub doesn't decide on context... it
    # just returns the perl default... a list in
    # list context, or the element count if in
    # scalar context

    return qw(1 2 3);
}
sub want_array {
    my @array = qw(1 2 3);

    # wantarray() can check if the caller wants a
    # list returned... if so, it can do one thing, 
    # if not, it can do something else

    return @array if wantarray;

    # return value of element 0 if scalar context
    # requested

    return $array[0];
}
```

Comment: what is use warnings;
use strict;

Comment: @alex [Here's](https://perlmaven.com/always-use-strict-and-use-warnings) a pretty decent tutorial. Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;` ;)